# Weightless and Visible, who am I?

Tags: word

> I am everywhere 
>   I am weightless 
>   You can see me. 
>   If you put me in a Bucket, 
>   Bucket gets lighter.

Who am I?

Comment: I heard this puzzle on a kids TV show, long time ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> a hole?

I am everywhere

> This probably either refers to holes all around us, e.g., keyholes, or anywhere we have air, i.e., not a solid object.

I am weightless

> A hole means lack of substance, so no weight.

You can see me.

> You can see the hole due to the fact you can see through it.

If you put me in a Bucket, 
Bucket gets lighter.

> Putting holes in a bucket removes material and makes it lighter.

Comment: Good answer - I wonder also does the answer with a 'w' in front of it sound like everywhere.

Answer (score 23):

You could be

> light

...beause...

> Light is found everywhere (all matter at temperature above absolute
>  zero emits thermal electromagnetic radiation) Photons have zero mass
>  (weightless) You can see light (depending on frequency of course) And
>  if you 'put' light in a bucket (shine a torch on it, add a candle,
>  etc), the interior of the bucket is less dark, i.e. lighter.

Comment: seems good, though, lighter refers to weight in the puzzle. :-)

Comment: _Bucket gets lighter_ If I shine a light, then did that fit the phrase? I don't think so.

Comment: Would have been my answer as well, phisically something weightless and visible reminds me of photons.

Comment: @RahulParashar - "holes" are not everywhere, "space" and "light" are. Putting space into a bucket only makes it lighter if it displaces something in the bucket. Putting light into a bucket certainly makes the bucket lighter (in brightness), therefore "light" is the correct answer.

Comment: Is there any other word for lighter, which would only mean by weight?

Comment: @RahulParashar: "weigh less"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: the bucket will weigh less because a hole will cause some matters from the bucket to be removed (the matters forming part of the buckets where the hole currently is). But I agree if the answer were light this puzzle would have been much better =D

Comment: @justhalf I did not dispute that fact, just that holes are not everywhere - indeed, even if there is no matter that can fall out through said hole the bucket will still be lighter (it will have a hole in it).

Answer (score -2):

> clouds

they are weightless but existed but can not an are weightless till they shift form into drops from the water vapors that forms them.